# Windows 8.1 TW700 Tablet microSD Card Seems Too Hot

Tags: windows-8.1, cooling, tablet, micro-sd-card

I picked up a TW700 tablet and, after some tinkering, managed to use NTFS junctions to move `\Program Files\` and `\Users\` to a microSD card to give myself some breathing room.

I'm not expecting much from the device since it was $60, but even just using Chrome with two tabs open, the microSD card and slot become extremely hot.  Even sitting at desktop after a cold boot, the card quickly heats up.

It's not too horrible an adventure to reverse my junctioning to take the load off the card, but my question is do I have to worry about the heat causing data loss or damage to the device?

Comment: I wonder if its the SD card or wider thermal issues. Kinda hard to test though, unless you can test it with load elsewhere, or a dummy card

Comment: If you're worried about data loss, then make sure you have a backup. The card (and even the internal eMMC) can fail at any time no matter what you do.

Comment: Most SD cards don't do any wear levelling, so don't last as long for frequent writes anyway. And, yes, high heat is bad for it, but also fairly normal - not much you can do about that.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek When I was creating the junctions, I had to do so from a recovery command prompt.  The process was basically copy from C:\ to D:\ (flashdrive) as the device didn't recognize the SD card in that state.  The USB connector of the drive got about as warm as the card feels.  I'm thinking this might be a flaw with the device itself, now.